# Как понять логику работы функции JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, функции

День добрый.
Не могу понять работу функции JS

При первом клике, все отлично, добавляю класс `colLeft_activity` и получаю элемент `aside.colLeft.colLeft_activity`.
При повторном клике надо убрать `.colLeft_activity`.

Если в саму консоль, после 1-го кли прописать `console.log($('aside.colLeft.colLeft_activity').length);` = 1(получаю).

Но если смотреть `function openCloseMenu(search_class, old_class, selectionElement, delete_class)` вижу 0.

Почему при каждом 2-ои и более клике вижу `console.log(search_class.length);` = 0

Вот переменные

```
var search_class = $('.colLeft_activity'); //The class which we search. This's a variable
var old_class = $('.colLeft'); // The element to which we will add the class. This's the variable
var selectionElement = 'colLeft colLeft_activity'; //Adds the new class. Type the text
var delete_class = 'colLeft_activity' //Class which delete. Type the text
```

Вот сама функция

```
function openCloseMenu(search_class, old_class, selectionElement, delete_class){
 
    
    console.log(search_class.length);
    
    // console.log($('.colLeft.colLeft_activity'));
    if (search_class.length == 0){
        old_class.addClass(selectionElement);
        console.log('3333');
    }
    
    else if (search_class.length >= 1) {
        console.log('55555');
        //search_class.removeClass(delete_class);
        $('.colLeft').removeClass('colLeft_activity');
    }
};
```

Вызываю функцию

```
$('aside.colLeft').click(function(){
    openCloseMenu(search_class, old_class, selectionElement, delete_class);
}
);
```

Консоль
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Как минимум то, что ты хардкорно пишешь через console.log - отличается от того, что ты передаёшь переменными.... И плюс addClass что в себя принимает и что ты ему передаёшь - тоже различаются

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, так addClass  в случае выполнения `if (search_class.length == 0)` условия. Тогда как преподнести `search_class.length` для проверки?

Comment: Подать на вход корректные данные

Comment: Спасибо. Проблему нашел, Ваша подсказка сработала.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем проблема была в обновлении данных, которые хранят переменные вовремя одной сессии.

Другими словами, при загрузке страницы, переменные
`var old_class,  var search_class,  var selectionElement,  var delete_class` переменные загружали в себя данные.

При повторном клике, переменные не обновляли данные. Они были прописаны вне функции.

```
$('aside.colLeft').click(function(){
    var data_length = $('.colLeft_activity').length
    
    var old_class = $('.colLeft'); // The element to which we will add the class. This's the variable
    var search_class = search_class; //The class which we search. This's a variable
    var selectionElement = 'colLeft colLeft_activity'; //Adds the new class. Type the text
    var delete_class = 'colLeft_activity' //Class which delete. Type the text

    openCloseMenu(search_class, old_class, selectionElement, delete_class, data_length);
    });
```

обновляет данные в переменных при каждом клике не селектор.